# Error while uploading app into Windows App Store - "native API api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-2-0.dll:InterlockedIncrement()" in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am trying to upload app into Windows Appstore and stuck at the following errors. I am using Sqlite and SQliteWinRTPhone in my app. What could be the problem. How to resolve this? Please check the pic of Configuration Manager also.

---

[image]

---

> 1028: The native API
>   api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-2-0.dll:InterlockedIncrement() isn’t
>   allowed in assembly SQLiteWinRTPhone.dll. Update it and then try
>   again.
>
> 1028: The native API
>   api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-2-0.dll:InterlockedCompareExchange()
>   isn’t allowed in assembly sqlite3.dll. Update it and then try again.
>
> 1028: The native API
>   api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-2-0.dll:InterlockedCompareExchange()
>   isn’t allowed in assembly SQLiteWinRTPhone.dll. Update it and then try
>   again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted the configuration into ARM configuration and the problem is fixed. Now the xap file is uploading into the appstore without errors. Also Sqlite and SQliteWinRTPhone are included in this xap file. My problem solved.